# DocumentDB Throughput Scale down from 1000 to 400

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

At first, I have created DocumentDB Collection with 2000 as Throughput. after I have realized that it is too high, I tried to reduce by clicking (-) button. It got reduce till 1000 after that it doesn't work. I want to set as 400.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately it is not possible to do so considering your collection is of unlimited size. Minimum throughput for such collection is 1000 RU/s (earlier it was 2500 RU/s).

If you want to have a collection with 400 RU/s, please create a new collection with fixed storage capacity (currently 10GB) and migrate the data from your existing collection to this new collection.

Comment: But I am able to create a collection with unlimited storage and 400 RU/s..

Answer (score 0):

There were some updates to the performance level of Cosmos DB recently. The previous [S1, S2, S3 performance levels have been retired](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/performance-levels). Now there are only two types of containers, *fixed* and *unlimited*. As Gaurav mentioned, the RU/s range for *fixed* is from 400 - 10,000, and for *unlimited* is from 1,000 - 100,000. And *unlimited* must have a partition key, while *fixed* doesn't have to.

More details can be found in this newly updated document: [Partition and scale in Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partition-data#prerequisites-for-partitioning). According to this document, my suggestions would be, even if you go and create a fixed container, you should still give it 1,000 RU/s and a partition key so you don't have to do migration in the future in case your data or load grows beyond the capacity of the fixed container.